# How can you make a new column that is based on a row where the values in that row are essentially A B A B A B and you want the new column to be B - A

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column of Arsenic values from well water testing and in that column the first value is from before a rain event and the second value is from after a rain event. I need to make a column that subtracts the pre-rain event value from the post-rain event value. Here is a simplified version of what I am working with and what I want to create:

| Well | Program | Arsenic | arsenic_change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Monthly | 3 |  |
| A | Rain Event | 4 | 1 |
| B | Monthly | 2 |  |
| B | Rain Event | 6 | 4 |
| C | Monthly | 1 |  |
| C | Rain Event | 1 | 0 |

How do I make that arsenic_change column?
Right now, I have tried to mutate using this code: mutate(arsenic_change = As - lag(As))
This subtracts the previous value from every row though, and I just need the monthly values subtracted from the Rain event values for each well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you were pretty close. Assuming your data is ordered in the correct way, you would just need to add a `group_by` for the Well so `dplyr` knows to only look at each Well separately rather than all rows in the data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  "Well" = rep(c("A", "B", "C") , each = 2),
  "Program" = rep(c("Monthly", "Rain Event") , 3),
  "Arsenic" = c(3, 4, 2, 6, 1, 1)
)

df <-
  df %>%
  group_by(Well) %>%
  mutate(arsenic_change = Arsenic - lag(Arsenic))

df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   Well [3]
#>   Well  Program    Arsenic arsenic_change
#>   <chr> <chr>        <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 A     Monthly          3             NA
#> 2 A     Rain Event       4              1
#> 3 B     Monthly          2             NA
#> 4 B     Rain Event       6              4
#> 5 C     Monthly          1             NA
#> 6 C     Rain Event       1              0
```

If it’s not ordered, because the program looks to be alphabetical order you could `arrange` it as well to make sure everything is properly ordered for `lag`.

```r
df <- tibble(
  "Well" = rep(c("A", "B", "C") , each = 2),
  "Program" = rep(c("Rain Event", "Monthly") , 3),
  "Arsenic" = c(4, 3, 6, 2, 1, 1)
)

df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   Well  Program    Arsenic
#>   <chr> <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1 A     Rain Event       4
#> 2 A     Monthly          3
#> 3 B     Rain Event       6
#> 4 B     Monthly          2
#> 5 C     Rain Event       1
#> 6 C     Monthly          1

df <-
  df %>%
  arrange(Well, Program) %>%
  group_by(Well) %>%
  mutate(arsenic_change = Arsenic - lag(Arsenic))

df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   Well [3]
#>   Well  Program    Arsenic arsenic_change
#>   <chr> <chr>        <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 A     Monthly          3             NA
#> 2 A     Rain Event       4              1
#> 3 B     Monthly          2             NA
#> 4 B     Rain Event       6              4
#> 5 C     Monthly          1             NA
#> 6 C     Rain Event       1              0
```

You can also use base R with the `ave` function and add any number of grouping variables.

```
df$arsenic_change <- ave(df$Arsenic, df$Well, FUN=function(x) c(NA, diff(x)))
```

e.g. with month (assuming it's ordered correctly as noted above)

```
df$arsenic_change <- ave(df$Arsenic, df$Well, df$Month, FUN=function(x) c(NA, diff(x)))
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you! Although, in my data there are eight entries for each well (a pre and post rain level for four different months - the table in my question was very simplified) Would grouping by well still work in that case?

Comment: So you have another column that identifies month as well? If that's the case, you would add the month to the group_by and it should work the same. group_by(Well, month). If not, can you add a little more detail about your data to the question?

Comment: Yes, that did the trick!!